# Recursive Alternative/Merge Linked List Function with Multiple Linked List as Arguments?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I'm having trouble working with recursive linked list function with multiple linked list arguments.

So far I have came up with below, with a single linked list and works fine.

```
def recursive_ll(ll):
    if ll == None:
        return None
    elif ll.next == None:
        return LN(ll.value)
    else:
        return_ll = LN(ll.value, recursive_ll(ll.next))
        if return_ll.value == return_ll.next.value:
            return_ll = return_ll.next
    return return_ll
```

Result will be:

```
ll = list_to_ll(['x','g','f','n'])
print(str_ll(recursive_ll(ll)))

x->g->f->n->None
```

But I am really confused with how I can create recursive linked list function with multiple linked lists as arguments.

For example, def recursive_ll(ll): will be def recursive_ll(ll, ll2):

And returned result would be

```
ll = recursive_ll(['a','x','b','e'])
ll2 = recursive_ll(['d','f','m'])

a->d->x->f->b->m->e->None
```

Again, desired result below, combined from two linked list:

```
a->d->x->f->b->m->e->None
```

Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry there was small mistake, it is fixed and code should work fine. And recursive_ll function will return a, d, x, f, b, m, and e (individually, using recursion) from two linked list, so a, x ,b, and e is from first linked list, and d, f, and m is from the second one.

Comment: That's an improvement—your edit fixes the first time that was done, but that same issue is present in the lines `ll = recursive_ll(['a','x','b','e'])` and `ll2 = recursive_ll(['d','f','m'])` a little further down. Basically the argument to `recursive_ll()` can't be a regular `list`. However, I think I now understand what you meant by "Alternative" is the question's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use classes instead of simple functions as helpers. And accept any iterable as the source for a linked list. If you implement iterators on the linked list class, that would allow trivial conversion between any iterable and a linked list.

The linked list class could be:

```
class LL:
    class iter:
        def __init__(self, ll):
            self.cur = ll.front
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            if self.cur is None:
                raise StopIteration()
            val = self.cur.value
            self.cur = self.cur.next
            return val

    def __init__(self, l):
        self.front = last = None
        for v in l:
            ln = LN(v)
            if last is None:
                self.front = ln
            else:
                last.next = ln
            last = ln

    def __str__(self):
        answer = ''
        for val in self.iter_elt():
            answer += str(val) + '->'
        return answer + 'None'

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ':' + str(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        return LL.iter(self)
```

This immediately allows:

```
>>> print(LL('abcd'))
a->b->c->d->None
>>> list(LL('abcd'))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

---

Once this is done, you can declare a Recursive Linked List as a subclass of a Linked List which allows to extract the elements in a merge order if it contains Linked Lists.

You should first add a new method `iter_elt` in `LL` class that just calls `iter` and use that in `__str__` to ease the subclassing:

```
class LL:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        answer = ''
        for val in self.iter_elt():
            answer += str(val) + '->'
        return answer + 'None'
    ...
    def iter_elt(self):
        return self.__iter__()
```

Because now, it is enough to override `iter_elt` in RLL, and build an iterator that will scan its sublists repeatedly calling `iter_elt` on them if possible else iter, until all are exhausted. Code could be:

```
class RLL(LL):
    class iter:
        def __init__(self, rll):
            self.iters = LL(i.iter_elt() if hasattr(i, 'iter_elt') else iter(i)
                            for i in rll)
            self.cur = self.iters.front
            self.prev = None
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            try:
                elt = next(self.cur.value)
                self.prev = self.cur
                self.cur = self.cur.next
                if self.cur is None:
                    self.cur = self.iters.front
                    self.prev = None
            except StopIteration:
                self.cur = self.cur.next
                if self.cur is None:
                    if self.prev is None:
                        raise
                    self.cur = self.iters.front
                    self.prev = None
                else:
                    if self.prev is None:
                        self.iters.front = self.cur
                    else:
                        self.prev.next = self.cur
                elt = self.__next__()
            return elt

    def iter_elt(self):
        return RLL.iter(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @Serge Ballesta that you should create a `LinkedList` class to do this, here's how it could be done the procedural way you're doing things.

Also note that it's not done recursively—but rather "pythonically".

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

class LN:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

def list_to_ll(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    front = rear = LN(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        rear.next = LN(v)
        rear = rear.next
    return front

def iterate(ll):
    while ll is not None:
        yield ll.value
        ll = ll.next

def str_ll(ll):
    return '->'.join(str(v) for v in iterate(ll)) + '->None'

def alternate(ll_1, ll_2):
    _NULL = object()
    chained = chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(iterate(ll_1), iterate(ll_2), 
                                              fillvalue=_NULL))
    return list_to_ll(list(v for v in chained if v is not _NULL))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ll_1 = list_to_ll(['a','x','b','e'])
    ll_2 = list_to_ll(['d','f','m'])

    print(str_ll(alternate(ll_1, ll_2)))  # -> a->d->x->f->b->m->e->None
```